# Potential resource leak: 'factory' may not be closed at this location

Tags: java

Im getting this error on resource:

> Potential resource leak: 'factory' may not be closed at this location

This is my code:

```
      ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
            Set<ConstraintViolation<RenewPackageRequest>> violations = validator.validate(request);
      
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(violations)) {
                error.throwValidationError(null, "Input parameters can't be null/empty");
            } else if (!YES.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRenewPackage()) && !NO.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRenewPackage())) {
                error.throwValidationError("RenewPackage", "parameter can only be YES/NO");
            }
   return resource;
```

I want to use try with resources but i dont know how to use.
I now that if i put factory.close() this error will disappear but this is not good praxis.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to use try with resources but i dont know how to use.

The java [Try-with-Resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) has a really simple syntax of

```
try (<declaration of closable resources>) {
    // code where you use those resources
}
```

So in your case a simple

```
try (ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();) {
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<RenewPackageRequest>> violations = validator.validate(request);

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(violations)) {
        error.throwValidationError(null, "Input parameters can't be null/empty");
    } else if (!YES.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRenewPackage()) && !NO.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRenewPackage())) {
        error.throwValidationError("RenewPackage", "parameter can only be YES/NO");
    }
    return resource;
}
```

should work.